# How does intersection form on vanishing cohomology determine hodge type?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

In the paper "Complete intersections with middle picard number 1 defined over Q" by Tomohide Terasoma (1985), [page 295](https://sci-hub.yncjkj.com/10.1007/bf01175050), line 7 from the bottom, we are in the following situation:

We have a smooth projective hypersurface $Y\subset\mathbb{P}^{2n+2}$, and a Lefschetz pencil $f\colon\overline{Y}\to\overline{D}\cong\mathbb{P}^1$ . The geometric generic fiber of the $f$ is denoted by $Y_\overline{\eta}$, it is a smooth hypersurface of dimension $2n$. The vanishing cohomology is defined as $$\mathrm{Ev}(Y):=\mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{H}^{2n}(Y,\mathbb{C})\to \mathrm{H}^{2n}(Y_{\overline{\eta}},\mathbb{C}))\cong \mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{H}^{2n}(Y_{\overline{\eta}},\mathbb{C})\to H^{2n+2}(Y,\mathbb{C})).$$ The goal is to show that

> If the monodromy action $$M\colon \pi_1(\overline{D}-\{s_1,...,s_d\})\to\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Ev}(Y))$$ has finite image, where $\{s_1,...,s_d\}$ are the singular fibers of $f$, then $\mathrm{H}^{2n}(Y_{\overline{\eta}},\mathbb{C})$ is of pure Hodge type $(n,n)$.

I'm confused about the following:

In the paper (line -10 page 295), it is argued that by some lattice theory, finiteness of $\mathrm{Im}(M)$ implies that the intersection form on $\mathrm{Ev}(Y)$ is positive or negative definite. Then this implies that $H^{2n}(Y_{\overline{\eta}},\mathbb{C})$ is of pure Hodge type $(n,n)$. How is the implication deduced?

Comment: Ok I the implication is deduced from the fact that the Hodge numbers $k\to h^{k,n-k}$ is  an increasing function, by SGA7.ii,XI.Thm 2.5(i).